# Unable to pull text from an element using Beautiful Soup in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull the text (see image of element tree) of an element in the trust pilot website using the following script but all it returns is a bunch of 'None'.

```
url = "https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/rockar.com"
try_url = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(try_url.content, 'html.parser')
print(try_url.content)

for h in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'styles_reviewContent__3TSDf'}):
    hdln = h.find("h2")
    print(hdln)
```

What is the way around this?
am I looking at the wrong selector?

[image]

Comment: I don't see "h2" in the div block.  Did you mean "hr"?

Comment: @Martin its in the 4th line from the bottom

Comment: the data is added with javascript. it is in a script tag `<script type="application/ld+json" data-business-unit-json-ld="true">`. search in the source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @diggusbickus pointed out, you can get the reviews this way:

```
data = json.loads(soup.find('script', type='application/json').string)
reviews = data["props"]["pageProps"]["reviews"]

sample_reply = reviews[0]["reply"]
```

The `sample_reply` is

```
{'message': "Thank you so much for your kind words, Fi! It's great to hear Shah was fantastic and offer a personal service to your car buying journey. Thank you for taking the time to leave us a great review! We hope you love your new vehicle! Thanks again for choosing Rockar :-)",
'publishedDate': '2021-11-04T12:35:25.401Z',
'updatedDate': '2021-11-04T12:35:34.948Z'}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now how do i fetch replies to the review, they aren't part of the json within the script

Comment: @SahalNurain, did you already try the code above and inspect the `reviews`? I suggest you check it since it contains all related data, reply included. For example, if you run those two lines and add `reviews[0]["reply"]`, you can get the reply message